# best method for hiding reponsive elements

Tags: jquery, css

I've been reading up on building mobile first responsive web pages.I'm new to web development so sorry about such trivial questions. In the write up i was reading he uses a jquery function to  get the clientwidth and the clientheight and then hiding a element at his breakpoint. Stupid question. Which way is more efficient, the way he does it or like so in the css.

`@media screen and (min-width: 28.75em){li{display: none;}
}`

Comment: $(w).resize(function(){ //Update dimensions on resize
  sw = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  sh = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  checkMobile();
});
  
//Check if Mobile
function checkMobile() {
  mobile = (sw > breakpoint) ? false : true;

  if (!mobile) { //If Not Mobile
    $('[role="tabpanel"],#nav,#search').show(); //Show full navigation and search
  } else { //Hide 
    if(!$('#nav-anchors a').hasClass('active')) {
      $('#nav,#search').hide(); //Hide full navigation and search
    }
  }
}

Comment: i coulnt get that^ in the original post but that would be the code i am reffering to as "his"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes there is benefit of using it. because for example some times we see the shortcodes are do not have css in style.css file and their attributes are also important in them. i mean sometimes we can not not find the these

> padding: 100px!important;
>
> margin: 100px!important;

so we use jquery to overwrite it ..to complete the website functioning

Answer (score -1):

i have read your question . which means you are working on a custom script for your website or for some one else.
do you need to use the jquery function for it

Comment: It's a custom script i guess you could say, its just for fun but also for learning. The jquery function doesn't have to be implemented but is there any benefits for using it?